# python: check auto log in to a website has been successful or not?

Tags: python, autologin

I use below python code for auto log in to a website. how to check log in has been successful or not?

> ```
> import requests
>
> URL = 'http://www.example.com'
>
> session = requests.session()
>
> login_data = dict(log='username', pwd='password')
> req = session.post(URL, data=login_data)
>
> print req.text
> ```

Comment: By checking the text returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think... it depends on the site you'd like to check.

- If the site provides an API to check authentication, you can use that.
- If the site does not, but alternatively, if the site provides any other APIs responding differently based on authentication, you can determine your current authentication status based on the response from API.
- If the site does not provides any APIs, but in the same vein with below assumptions, you can determine the status by checking on HTML responses anyway.
- If you find yourself being able to assure that there's any authentication determinant e.g. Cookie or HTTP Response Header being created only after successful login, you can check them out.